# To write diagram with injective arrow

Tags: amsmath, diagrams, tikz-cd

I want to write the following diagram.
[image]

I wrote following code, **but I cannot out put the injective map from $A$ to $B$**.　How can I do that and I can write beautiful diagram ?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm and 3cm, auto]
  \node (A) {A};
  \node (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \node (C) [below=of A] {C};
  \node (D) [below=of B] {D};
  \node (E) [right=of D] {E};
  \node (F) [right=of E] {F};

  \draw[->] (A) -- (B) node[midway,above] {$\hookrightarrow$};
  \draw[->] (A) -- (C);
  \draw[->] (B) -- (D);
  \draw[->] (C) -- (D);
  \draw[->] (D) -- (E) node[midway,above] {$f_1$};
  \draw[->] (E) -- (F) node[midway,above] {$f_2$};
  \draw[->] (B) -- (E) node[midway,sloped,above] {$f$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Ok, don't get what you are missing. Can you please EDIT your question and explain a little more? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of manually creating your diagram in tikz, have instead a look at the tikz-cd package:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \arrow[r, hook] \arrow[d] & B\arrow[d]\arrow[dr,"f"]\\
  C \arrow[r] & D \arrow[r,"f_1"] & E \arrow[r,"f_2"] & F
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `tikz-cd` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large]
  A \arrow[r, hook] \arrow[d] &
  B \arrow[d] \arrow[dr,"f"]
\\
  C \arrow[r] & D \arrow[r,"f_2"'] & E \arrow[r] & F
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I feel somewhat unsatisfied by the diagonal arrow; changing the anchor point does a batter job. You can first draft your diagrams in an easy way and reserve some time at the end for fine tuning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large]
  A \arrow[r, hook] \arrow[d] &
  B \arrow[d] \arrow[dr,start anchor=base east,"f"]
\\
  C \arrow[r] & D \arrow[r,"f_2"'] & E \arrow[r] & F
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note how the `hook` arrow and the labels are specified; a single quote after the closing `"` for the label means that the label should go on the right side of the arrow (default is the left side, determined in the same way as for rivers, that is, facing the end).